# Insert <span> in <p> element

Tags: javascript, css, text, html

I got like;

```
<p>Variable Text</p>
```

And I want to it to be;

```
<p>Variable <span>Text</span></p>
```

Is this possible by a javascript function? / or jQuery.

Oh yeah, and the p-element got an ID and the text inside the p-element is variable but always consists of 2 words. I want a span around the last word of the text by a javascript function.

Comment: jQuery / Javascript, doesn't really matter to me. As long as it works ..

Comment: @AnoniemAnoniem posted a new answer

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this

```
var txt = "Hello bye";
var dataArr = txt.split(' ');

var paragraph = document.getElementById("pid");
paragraph.innerHTML = dataArr[0]+ " <span>"+dataArr[1]+"</span>";
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yX37b/)

Comment: glad it helped...And don't forget to upvote or mark as answer ;)

Comment: I had to wait before I was able to mark it as answer, you were too quick!

Answer (score 5):

It's possible (the following assumes the `p` has an ID, like you said), in it's simplest form you can just do:

```
var paragraph = document.getElementById("pId");
paragraph.innerHTML = "Hello <span>World</span>";
```

Or if you want to use jQuery:

```
$("#pId").html("Hello <span>World</span>");
```

Or (as you said in comments, you want to keep the existing content, but wrap the last word in a `span`, you can do:

```
var newHTML = $("#pId").html().replace(" ", " <span>");
$("#pId").html(newHTML).append("</span>");
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9f5Gj/)

Comment: @Downvoter Care to comment? Is it because I didn't use jQuery? Wake up and smell the coffee, there is JavaScript outside of the world of jQuery.

Comment: But the text inside the <p> is variable and always consists of two words. I want the <span> around the last (second) word (the one after the whitespace) in it.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object <span> has no method 'append' ?

Answer (score 1):

I would like to share a jQuery solution, which is regardless of any words defined in your `p` element

```
$("p").html(function(){
    var mystring= $(this).text().split(" ");
    var lastword = mystring.pop();
    return mystring.join(" ")+ (mystring.length > 0 ? " <span>"+ lastword + "</span>" : lastword);
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/eBpk3/)

In the demo above, I am splitting the string first, than am using `pop` to get the last index in the array, and than am adding `span` element and returning the string using `join`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("document").ready(function(){
  $("p").append("<span>world</span>");
});
```

Comment: But the text inside the <p> is variable and always consists of two words. I want the <span> around the last (second) word in it.

Answer (score 0):

With JQuery append

```
$("#paragraphId").append('<span>Text in span</span>');
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is easier, and personally I think it's better to use than only javascript:

jQuery:

```
$("#paragraphID").append("<span>World</span>");
```

HTML:

```
<p id="paragraphID">Hello</p>
```