# Select/Apply Styles to specific character with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I write code instead of using camelCase or seperate_with_underscore I separate my class names with custom unicode chars. Such as this:

sideNavܢheaderܢtext

So if I have a class with a specific state modifier I will write it like so:

sideNavܢheaderܢtextᆞbold

These are not css selectors this is just my naming convention. Now for my question.

I am using the atom text editor and sometimes I want to be able to hide these special characters. I can use javascript to select things in Atom, but is it possible to use javascript to literally select a single character?

Then I can use that selection to apply a "display:none" style to it?

Like:

```
var a = document.getElementByChar("a");
a.style.display = "none";
```

Any help or ideas would be appreciated!

Update: I don't want to actually remove the characters. Just "hide" them from view. The naming convention I use is actually much more complex than this and I use these special characters to define all sorts of patterns in my document.

However sometimes I only care about certain selectors and I want the others to temporarily go away.

Comment: No. You would need to wrap that character in an element like `<span>` and hide the element

Comment: Awww, I figured that. Well thanks for confirming it. I'll find some other way.

Comment: You can use String#replace() to replace a character with an element wrapping it if needed

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, in JavaScript you can:

1. Get the entire string from the className:

`const string = document.querySelector(".sideNavܢheaderܢtext").textContent`

2. Find the location of the character you want to modify. For example:

`string.indexOf('a')`.

3. Wrap the character with a `span` (plenty of ways to do that - check out [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19154336/insert-span-in-p-element)).
4. Add class to span and style with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Atom. Are each of these selectors within dom elements in Atom?

If all of your selectors existed within `<span class="selector">` then you could do something like this...

```
$('span.selector').each(function(elm){
    $(elm).text($(elm).text().split('ܢ').join('<b style="display:none;">ܢ</b>'));
});
```